# Drupal 8 CKEeditor license/pricing

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Drupal 8 ships with ckeditor as the default text editor. Drupal itself can be used free of charge without limitations. At least this is what I thought until now.

While CKEditor seems to be OpenSource, the website suggests there is a price depending on how it will be used. E.g. if a project has more than 2 developers, or more than 5 content editors.
https://ckeditor.com/pricing/

How does this play together? What am I missing? Is there a special license when using CKEditor in a Drupal project?

Comment: This has never come up on any project I've done with CKEditor since Drupal 7. As far as I know it can be used completely free of charge, regardless of user count. It sounds like you are basically buying into dedicated support services for CKEditor.

Comment: "Compared to Open Source which comes with a multitude of obligations, the obvious advantage is a legal one: commercial licenses do not require you to share your source code with the public in any way. Also, commercial licenses come with another equally important advantage: support. Our support team can make sure that you understand and integrate the editor correctly, and will be there to help in case you run into a wall."

Answer (score 4):

Both Drupal and CKEditor are licensed under GPL2+.

See https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/991 and https://www.drupal.org/about/licensing.

CKEditor is not the only open source project offering commercial licensing. See the [FAQ](https://ckeditor.com/pricing#faq).